# Get local PHP page as external client

Tags: php, local

I wish to call a local PHP page with PHP with the server side code already executed.

For instance, if I have a page with the following content:

```
Hello, this is <?php $name="John"; echo $name ?>
```

I wish to have a get command such as file_get_contents(local_php_page) or fopen(handle) return:

```
Hello, this is John
```

Rather than

```
Hello, this is <?php $name="John"; echo $name ?>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output Buffering should be able to do that for you:

```
ob_start();
include 'myfile.php';
$xhtml = ob_get_clean();
```

You could also get the output of your include, eg:

```
$xhtml = include 'myfile.php';
```

For more on this, check out [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 0):

As you've already mentioned you can use [file_get_contents](http://de3.php.net/file_get_contents) to send a get request to any http url. You have to make sure, that [allow_url_fopen](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled. Of course your webserver has to be configured to handle php requests correctly

```
<?php
$requestUrl = 'http://localhost/your_file.php';
$content = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
var_dump($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have allow_url_fopen in your server, you might use fopen with an url.

Answer (score 0):

Need to call http url instead of path

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/yourpath/";
$str=file_get_contents($url."/yourfile.php");
echo $str;
```